# How is it possible for ethereum-bridge to deploy a contract at a deterministic address?

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, oracles

Here I provide a snippet of the output generated by `ethereum-bridge` on startup:

```
[2017-10-13T07:25:55.920Z] INFO deploying the oraclize connector contract...
[2017-10-13T07:26:16.357Z] INFO connector deployed to: 0x3ae9795a5c4ef9f803d56437163b3abd39649525
[2017-10-13T07:26:16.482Z] INFO deploying the address resolver with a deterministic address...
[2017-10-13T07:26:47.730Z] INFO address resolver (OAR) deployed to: 0x6f485c8bf6fc43ea212e93bbf8ce046c7f1cb475
```

Indeed, the address of the OAR contract is always `0x6f485c8bf6fc43ea212e93bbf8ce046c7f1cb475`, but as the contract's address is determined by hashing the sender's account + nonce, how can Oraclize (`ethereum-bridge`) always deploy to the same address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is very simple, they use the same account and only with nonce = 0. From their [github repo](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge/blob/e56a9349fa92e830aa14b99c03183ffceabefc8a/lib/bridge-account.js#L7)

```
// used only to deploy a deterministic address resolver (OAR) (contract address = sha3(rlp.encode([normalize_address(sender), nonce]))[12:])
const OAR_ONLY_PRIV_KEY = Buffer.from('79a98ade62c92444178d73409fbce37a360b36a2483dda666d26270c8a50f5c7', 'hex')
const OAR_ONLY_ADDRESS = '0x935A0F8F4B8752C61f00D1f67b67685665ff8Cf6'
```

---

In the same file bridge-account.js they have the following functions

```
BridgeAccount.prototype.getTempAddress = function () {
  return OAR_ONLY_ADDRESS
}

BridgeAccount.prototype.getTempPrivKey = function () {
  return OAR_ONLY_PRIV_KEY
}
```

In the function deployOAR in [bridge-core.js](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge/blob/e56a9349fa92e830aa14b99c03183ffceabefc8a/lib/bridge-core.js#L104) they have the following

```
BridgeTxManager().sendRawTx({
    'from': self.account, 
    'data': oraclizeAddressResolverBin, 
    'gas': 324702, 
    '$temporary_account': true}, function (err, contract) {
```

The important part is `'$temporary_account': true`

Now looking at sendRawTx in [bridge-tx-manager.js](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-bridge/blob/f9241b8afa9cea0f7075d67249fac2ced3852c9b/lib/bridge-tx-manager.js#L52) we have

```
BlockchainInterface().inter.sendRawTransaction(
    this.buildLocalTx(txData), function (err, hash) {
```

In buildLocalTx we have

```
var broadcastAccount = this.account
var broadcastPrivateKey = this.privateKey()
if (typeof txData['$temporary_account'] !== 'undefined' && txData['$temporary_account'] === true) {
  broadcastAccount = BridgeAccount().getTempAddress()
  broadcastPrivateKey = BridgeAccount().getTempPrivKey()
}
```

When the parameter `$temporary_account` is set to true it will use the hardcoded values in bridge-account.

Comment: But how do they get their account? And how do they send from it?

Comment: What is the OAR_ONLY_PRIVATE_KEY used for?

Comment: @Shuzheng I've added how the values are used to generate the deterministic address. Now you have to convince yourself that all other possible configurations will not generate a deterministic address, or better check for yourself.

Comment: Using a chosen private key, can one generate a public key? In other words, for each private (or public) key, there exists only one public (private) key? Of course it must be hard to generate the private key from the public key, but the other direction is easy?

Comment: @Shuzheng That is a different matter, you should create a new question for it. I think you are right but I don't know enough about elliptic curves to answer trustfully.