# How come SHIB and CAKE wallet just use the same Ethereum address?

Tags: wallets

I created some wallets on the Exodus app, including SHIB, CAKE, and ETH, but I noticed that the SHIB and CAKE address is the same as the ETH address.

Using unMineable to mine, the wallets are also:

```
SHIB:0xc823_________________
CAKE:0xc823_________________
```

Why is that?  Do some cryptos use the same Ethereum wallet to store them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it possible for ethereum-bridge to deploy a contract at a deterministic address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28391/how-is-it-possible-for-ethereum-bridge-to-deploy-a-contract-at-a-deterministic-a)

Comment: I don't quite get it. Can it be more in plain English?

Comment: @nonopolarity SHIB (0x95aD61..) and CAKE (0x0E09Fa..) don't have the same address.  Probably you have the same wallet, that is perfectly fine. Any Ethereum compatible chain can use the same wallet to store ERC20 or BEP20 tokens, e.g. ETH mainnet, BSC, etc.

Comment: I guess a vague answer is: because SHIB and CAKE are not "Coins" -- they don't have a blockchain. They are "Tokens", and they rely on something else, in this case, Ethereum, and from the Exodus wallet, ETH, SHIB, and CAKE all gives me the same ETH address... but this is just a vague answer... how does SHIB and CAKE "base it on" ETH?